# How do I prove that $\log(1/b)^x= -\log b^x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I prove that $\log(1/b)^x= -\log b^x$?

I am working on logarithm properties. And I have come across one of the power rules, where the base is a fraction. I'm struggling to make assumptions and prove that the two equations are equal. Someone to help.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: What properties do you already have proved?

Comment: I proved the quotient rule.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to ask for a proof of$$\log_{1/b}{(x)}=-\log_b{(x)}$$

Comment: Yes, you are very right,  that is my question.  Sorry for confusion.  Error in typing.

Comment: Note:  $b^k = x \iff (\frac 1b)^{-k} = x$.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the following laws of exponents  $$a^{-m}=\frac1{a^m}, \qquad (a^m)^n=a^{mn}=(a^n)^m$$
and the power law of logarithms $$\log_b x^n=n\log_bx.$$

Solution:

> We have $$\log\left(\frac1b\right)^x=\log(b^{-1})^x=\log(b^x)^{-1}=-\log b^x$$ as desired.

Comment: That one I managed to prove it.  I was asking for the one were we have  log of 1/b (x) = -logb (x). What properties should I use?

Comment: It's not clear in your question. Perhaps edit it to clarify it.

Comment: What do you mean "that one I managed to prove it"? This answer is answering **completely and exactly** what you asked ! I only hinted...

Comment: I like the surpise with the gray background :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For any $\;a,b\in (0,\infty)\;$ , we have that

$$\log\frac ab=\log a-\log b$$

But we also know that $\;\log 1=\ldots?$

Answer (score 1):

---

**You want to show:**
$$\log(1/b)^x= -\log b^x$$

---

We need to use two Theorems for this.

$\bullet~$**Theorem 1:** Let $a, b > 0$. Then $\log(a/b) = \log(a) - \log(b)$

*Proof:* Let, $u = \log a$ and $v = \log b$. Let the base be $10$ wlog. Therefore from the definition of $\log$, we have that
$$ \log a = u \implies 10^u = a \quad \text{ and } \quad \log b = v \implies 10^v = b $$
Hence, $$ \frac{10^u}{10^v} = 10^{u - v} = \frac{a}{b} \implies u - v = \log\left(\frac{a}{b} \right) = \log a - \log b $$

$\bullet~$**Theorem 2:** Let $a > 0$ and $m \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\log(a^m) = m\log(a)$

*Proof:* Let $u = \log (a^m)$ then we have that
$$ u = \log (a^m) \implies 10^u = a^m \implies 10^{u / m} = a \implies \frac{u}{m} = \log (a) \implies u = \log(a^m) = m \log (a) $$

---

Thus by **Theorem 1** and **Theorem 2** we have $$\log(1/b)^x= x (\log(1) - \log(b) ) = -x \log (b) =  -\log b^x$$

---

**Edit:** $\log 1 = 0$.

*proof:* Let's take $u > 0$. Then
$$ u^0 = 1 \implies 0 \cdot \log(u) = \log(1) \implies \log(1) = 0 $$

Answer (score 1):

Claim:  $\log_{\frac 1b} x = -\log_b x$.

Pf:  $b^k = x \iff (\frac 1b)^{-k} =x$.

So $\log_b x = k \iff \log_{\frac 1b} x = -k$.

That's all.

=====

Alternatively the change of base theorem stats $\log_m k = \frac {\log_b k}{\log_b m}$ so $\log_{\frac 1b} x = \frac {\log_b k}{\log_b \frac 1b}=\frac {\log_b k}{-1} =-\log_b k$.

Of course we have to prove the change of base theorem.

Theres also this:  $\log_m (n)\log_n k = \log_n (k) \log_m n = \log_m n^{\log_n k} = \log_m k$[1].

So $\log_{\frac 1b} (x) = \log_{\frac 1b} (b) \log_b (x) = -\log_b x$.

=======

[1](Which is how you prove the change of base theorem:  $\log_n k = \frac {\log_m k}{\log_m n}$).